# Messages are displayed out of order in comet-chat

Tags: php, zend-framework, comet

I have integrated `comet` chat with `Zend`.

The problem is when user sends multiple messages within particular second (SS), those multiple messages are saved with same timestamp. So while displaying messages, it loads those multiple messages in random order.

is there any solution?